# Webpack@4.0.0: "Module parse failed. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type" - though using css-loader and style-loader

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

Below is my webpack.config.js and the package.json

```json
module.exports = {
  entry: "./entry.js",
  output: {
     filename: "./build/js/bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.\js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ["es2015"]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /.\css?$/,
    include: __dirname + "./src/css",
    exclude: __dirname + "./src/js",
    use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: true
          }
        }
      ]
  }
]
  },
  plugins: [
     // new UglifyJsPlugin()
  ]
}


"dependencies": {
    "ajv-keywords": "^3.1.0",
    "ajv": "^6.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "install": "^0.10.4",
    "npm": "^5.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.10",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.2",
    "webpack": "^4.0.0"
  },
```

Below is the error

> ERROR in ./src/css/autosuggest-style.css Module parse failed:
>   Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. | .ngCustomInput *, *:before, *:after { |
>   -moz-box-sizing: border-box; |     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;  @ ./entry.js 20:0-42
>
> ERROR in ./src/css/newUiStyles.css Module parse failed: Unexpected
>   token (1:4) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file
>   type. | body{ |   background-color: #F2F2F2; |   font-family:
>   sans-serif;  @ ./entry.js 3:0-36    ERROR in
>   ./src/css/custom-style.css Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:0)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. | /*
>   Styles go here */ | .border | { |     border:1px solid transparent;  @
>   ./entry.js 21:0-37

Not sure what error is....

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please look at your regex for matching. It is wrong.
It should be:

`/\.css$/` for css

`/\.js$/` for js

Your backslash is at the wrong position.
Your regex matches files named: style\css